# filter rest api post by a acf filed

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, filters, rest-api

I have 2 custom post type (songs, artists) that are connected with each other by relation field, every songs post have a relation field that store artist that relate the song post.

I'm getting data for mobile app via rest API
but I need filter API result post based on `ACF` field like getting songs post that related to an artist post.

Rest API : http://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/songs

I need something like : http://www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/songs?artist=1234
that return songs post that artist field is 1234

I found some tutorial but they are more than 2 years old and don't work now.

Comment: Can You share Your register_rest_route function for this endpoint ?

Comment: i don't understand , this endpoint relate to custom post type